# Windows / Powershell get Program Version into variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm close but not there.  I can get the version of my application via powershell, but it's got a bunch of text along with it.

This command:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    (get-item -Path 'c:\myapp.exe').VersionInfo ^| ^
        Format-List -Force | findstr "ProductVersion" > c:\version.txt
```

produces (in a text file): 
ProductVersion   : 1.6.7.0

Is it possible via a single command in powershell to split it?  I can't run ps scripts in my environment.  But if I could, I would run this:

```
$mystr = (get-item -Path 'c:\myapp.exe').VersionInfo | Format-List -Force | findstr ProductVersion
$arr = $mystr -split ": "
$arr[1]
```

Is there a way to put this on a single line and put it into a environment (batch) variable?

Comment: instead of `findstr`, powershell already have `sls` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your provided method, *with some modification*, perhaps this would do it?

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Powershell -C^
 "(GI 'C:\myapp.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"') Do Set "PV=%%A"
Echo=%PV%
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Mayhap

```
 | for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "ProductVersion"') do echo %%a>filename
```

or

```
 | for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "ProductVersion"') do set "prodver=%%a"
```

or

```
 | for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "ProductVersion"') do setx prodver "%%a"
```

but no guarantees. Note the `setx` version may establish a registry entry for future process instances, not for the current instance. `/m` would need to be added to make it a HKLM instead of a HKCU variable (if it works)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use WMIC to get version of your application :

```bat
@echo off
Title Get File Version of any Application using WMIC
Set "Version="
Set "AppFullPath=%Windir%\notepad.exe"
Call :Get_AppName "%AppFullPath%" AppName
Call :Add_backSlash "%AppFullPath%"
Call :GetVersion %Application% Version
If defined Version (
    echo Vesrion of %AppName% ==^> %Version%
)
pause>nul & Exit
::*******************************************************************
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Add_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:GetVersion <ApplicationPath> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application
Rem without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
 'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get version /format:Textvaluelist 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ProductVersion` property on the `VersionInfo` object and assign the result to an environment variable:

```
$ENV:MyEnvVariable = (get-item -Path 'c:\myapp.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```