# How can I get the properties of an application file from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, wmic

I am trying to get the properties of a .exe file.

If I use `wmic datafile where name="${localPath}" get Version`, 
I can get the version of the application.

However, I want the `product version` field from the properties and cannot get it from the command line directly.
All that WMIC can give me are:
AccessMask, Archive, Caption, Compressed, CompressionMethod, CreationClassName, CreationDate, CSCreationClassName, CSName, Description, Drive, EightDotThreeFileName, Encrypted, EncryptionMethod, Extension, FileName, FileSize, FileType, FSCreationClassName, FSName, Hidden, InstallDate, InUseCount, LastAccessed, LastModified, Manufacturer, Name, Path, Readable, Status, System, Version and Writeable.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Quite simple answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1550761/1338108

Answer (score 2):

I ended using powershell:
`powershell.exe Get-ItemProperty myApplication.exe -Name VersionInfo`

Then I was able to parse the output of the call in node.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product version with powershell and WMIC in the same batch file.

Just copy and save this code as ***Get_Application_Version.bat***

```bat
@Echo Off
Mode 80,10 & color 0A
Title Version With PowerShell
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603697/windows-powershell-get-program-version-into-variable/49607234#49607234
Set "AppFullPath=%Windir%\notepad.exe"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Powershell -C "(GI '%AppFullPath%').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"') Do Set "PV=%%A"
Echo Version of this Application "%AppFullPath%"=%PV%
Pause
Title Get File Version of any Application using WMIC
Rem WMIC
Set "Version="
Set "AppFullPath=%Windir%\notepad.exe"
Call :Get_AppName "%AppFullPath%" AppName
Call :Add_backSlash "%AppFullPath%"
Call :GetVersion %Application% Version
If defined Version (
    echo Vesrion of %AppName% ==^> %Version%
)
pause>nul & Exit
::*******************************************************************
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:Add_backSlash <String>
Rem Subroutine to replace the simple "\" by a double "\\" into a String
Set "Application=%1"
Set "String=\"
Set "NewString=\\"
Call Set "Application=%%Application:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
:GetVersion <ApplicationPath> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application
Rem without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
 'wmic datafile where "name='%~1'" get version /format:Textvaluelist 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
```